# Need help understanding how to run an app from docker.io

Tags: docker, centos7

Newer to Docker and trying to understand how images work.  I ran the following command:

```
sudo docker search hello-world
```

and it returned this:

```
docker.io   docker.io/carinamarina/hello-world-app               This is a sample Python web application,
```

I then ran:

```
sudo docker run docker.io/carinamarina/hello-world-app
```

...and this was the output from the terminal:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I don't understand.  How can the IP address be 0.0.0.0?  I entered that into a browser and got nothing.  I tried localhost:5000 and got nothing.

How does one get to see this webapp run?

Comment: side-note you can remove the sudo from the command by following those steps herehttps://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: You might work through [Docker's official quickstart documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) which covers many of the basics like this.

Comment: @David Mize.  I looked at that page before coming here.  It's how I know how to use docker run.  It's what they present.  I didn't see the part where the instructions are for connecting to 0.0.0.0:5000.

Answer (score -1):

**tl;dr**

you need to publish the port to the host network to see the application working

**long version:**

well good for you to start working with docker

I will start with explaining a little bit about docker then I will explain what is happing over there

First of all, there is a difference between "image" and "container"

- Image is the blueprint that is used to create containers from
  so you write the definition of the image like (install this, copy that from the host or build that.......etc) in the image file and then you tell docker to build this image and then RUN containers from that image

so if you have like 1 image and you run 2 containers from it they both will have the same instructions( definition )

**what happened with you**

when you invoke the RUN command first thing you will see is

> Unable to find image 'carinamarina/hello-world-app:latest' locally

That's mean that the local docker will not find the image(blueprint) locally with the name docker.io/carinamarina/hello-world-app so it will do the following steps

- so it will start pulling the image from the remote registry
  then
- then it will start extracting the layers of the image
- then it will start the container and show the logs from INSIDE CONTAINER

**Why it didn't run with you**

- the application is running inside the container on port 5000
- the container has a whole different network than the host that's running on (centos7 machine in your case )
- you will have to make a port forwarding between the docker network and the host network so you can USE the application from the HOST
- you can read more about that here [docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

I recommend the following places to start with

[let's play with docker](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/)

[docker tutorial for beggines](https://docker-curriculum.com/)

Comment: > Unable to find image 'carinamarina/hello-world-app:latest' locally.  I did not get that error.  I don't understand your reply.

Comment: I clicked on yoru docker networking like and followed instructions for docker run -p, like so sudo docker run -p 192.168.0.11:5000:80 docker.io/carinamarina/hello-world-app.  When I go to the browser I get a connection error... still not working.

Comment: @MGoBlue93 a simple run like  docker run -p 80:5000 docker.io/carinamarina/hello-world-app  will do the trick 
also please read the tutorial 
-p 8080:80  Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.
so it's like -p host_port:container_port